# The single-power-button logic of the cell phone

Tags: power-management

As known the cell phone has a single power button (most if not all), long press of it can power on the phone or choose to turn off the phone in the UI (my phone is Samsung). I wonder how is it implemented internal. Will the power button complete cut off the power supply from the battery? Or the phone never be cut off from the battery completely and there are some daemon code (like sleep or stand by mode of some MCU) to monitor the power button event?

Anyone has some clues\docs\links?

Comment: There is a dedicated IC monitoring the button, or more likely integrated with other related features on the reset controller IC, The buttons are smart, likely no software daemon but embedded firmware or hardcoded rom sending interrupt to CPU

Comment: You might read [this link](http://www.mosaic-industries.com/embedded-systems/microcontroller-projects/electronic-circuits/push-button-switch-turn-on/latching-toggle-power-switch) for some thoughts to consider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reset/power controller IC , in marketing speak "Power Management IC" **PMIC** is a common approach, for a large cellphone mfg this may be a custom chip with bespoke features for their product and to support extended button features and signals

In the most common  case these ICS allow configuration of reset sources and inputs. They also manage the order of how things turn on . They may also have multiple voltage regulators integrated so a designer can save space with one IC for all your voltage and reset  needs

A common scenario is to have a PMIC monitor supply voltage levels and reset (shutdown) system when voltage drops below a certain threshold. This can be a complex sequence of steps , turning off certain ICs in a correct order to have everything safe.

PMIC also have input sources to trigger this reset/shutdown. This may be a logic line from an MCU or other controller (say battery charge controller to turn off if there is overcurrent), a watchdog , or a button input.

In that scenario the PMIC is configured or designed to assert reset when a certain input is held for a specific timeout . This same input can drive a GPIO pin for other things like volume or screenshot.

. Of course a simple button can be interfaced as an interrupt line to the processor and have daemon or driver monitoring the pin state , but this would be not very good, it means a software glitch could prevent shutdown without removing battery, and does not allow for power on very easily.

The level of integration of a PMIC is only really necessary on something like a cellphone, with premium on space. The same functionality can be replicated by using discrete components with hardcoded reset logic

Answer (score 2):

1. PMIC, per the answer from @crasic.
2. Any device (e.g. microcontroller) that has a zero-power or near-zero power sleep mode. For example [Microchip offers parts with sleep currents in the nA range](https://www.microchip.com/design-centers/lowpower). (Just use an interrupt pin to wake back up.) Processor will control power to the rest of the circuit.
3. A discrete solution is a circuit that I've heard called a "suicide circuit" because the host processor can cut off its own power. However when I try to Google the term "suicide circuit" I get hard-core workout routines and commentaries about stand-up comedians who have been pushed to the edge. I guess "suicide circuit" isn't exactly standard terminology. Anyway, here is the basic concept for the circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQgolJ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

- When SW1 is pushed, Q1 gets turned on and power is supplied to PWR_IN.
- Once the processor is awake (optionally with some debounce time / reads) it asserts HOLD_PWR_ON. This turns on Q2.
- At this point, Q1 will remain on regardless of whether or not SW1 is still pressed or not.
- ...and the SW1 input can be used as a standard switch to be read by the processor.
- When it's time to power down, the processor sets HOLD_PWR_ON low and cuts its own power.

This of course can be done with FETs instead of BJTs if desired. As you'd probably guess, you want devices with nice low leakage in the OFF state. And it needs a processor (or PMIC) that wakes up quickly to set HOLD_PWR_ON, to guard against to short of a press time on SW1.